# Javascript Vue import from @ symbol

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to understand how this `import   from @`  I can't run npm run dev because the module is not found. I think I'm missing something, below are the screenshot and the errors.

[image]

As you can see Module not found because of `@`

[image]

Here is my route.js that has `@` .

Comment: Is this built with the vue cli?

Comment: @Phix - Laravel mix

Comment: Do any other imports with the `@` alias work correctly? I don't know about Laravel mix but typically, `@` is aliased to the `src` directory in a Vue CLI generated app.

Comment: Seems this is not a Laravel Mix feature. See https://laravel-news.com/laravel-mix-alias